# Unable to create ArcGIS network dataset perhaps due to size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have a large (several hundred thousands vectors, 800-900) from which I am trying to create a network (road) and am unable .  Don't sure if its an issue with ArcGIS or limitations with my computer.  That said are there any alternative methods of creating LARGE network data sets.

Comment: It's not a limitation of ArcGIS, I'm on ArcGIS 10.2 and just created a road network dataset of about 800,000 features, it worked fine and only took a few minutes. This is on a machine with a solid state hard drive and 24GB RAM and an older Xeon CPU.

Comment: I would first try exporting a smaller sub-set of the data and building it from that.  If it works with that, then it would likely either be a data limit (I'd be surprised if that was the case), or to me more likely it could be a corrupted feature or such.  Try running check and/or repair geometry tools on the whole dataset and see if it's a data problem rather than a feature limit.  Not sure it will fix it, but it's never a bad idea to try.  Also, what's your data source (File GDB, SDE, Personal GDB...?) Have you tried an alternate data source?

Comment: I'll look into both comments.  Its an SDE file which I exported to the computers hard drive thinking it may have been connectivity issues.  I ultimately have ~3 million  + features.

Comment: Is there an error message? Does it just fail without doing anything? Does it crash, lock up, or just return to normal without producing a result?

Comment: @Chris W.  Just runs and runs and runs - over an hour. I'm going to try a smaller subsection and then scale up from that to see what happens